# Every prime power $p^k$ that divides $\binom{2m}{m}$ is smaller than or equal to $2m$

Tags: number-theory

I want to show that every prime power $p^k$ that divides $\binom{2m}{m}$ is smaller than or equal to $2m$.

As a first step, I looked at
$$\binom{2m}{m}
= \frac{(2m)!}{(m!)^2}
= \frac{2m(2m-1) \ldots (m+2)(m+1)}{m!} \, .$$
Here I'm essentially stuck. I can apply the prime factorization to numerator and denominator, then I can cancel and I know that $p^k$ is left over in the numerator. But I cannot conclude $p^k \leq 2m$.

I feel that some vital ingredient is missing here, but I don't know what it is.

(Post edited with respect to the helpful comment.)

Comment: $\binom 21=2$ is an exception

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's supposed to be "smaller or equal" and $p^k \leq 2m$. I dropped that because I wasn't aware of the exception. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\alpha_{n, p}$ be the largest natural number such that $p^{\alpha_{n, p}}\mid n!$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p$ prime. Then $$\alpha_{n, p}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left[\frac{n}{p^k}\right]},$$ where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.

Comment: Does that help, @Amarus?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out. We want to count with what multiplicity $p$ occurs in the prime factorization of $n! \,$. $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \right\rfloor$ is the number of elements in $\left\{1, \ldots, n\right\}$ that are divided by $p$ at least once, $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^2} \right\rfloor$ the number of such elements that are divided by $p$ at least two times and so on. So we can add those up until $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor$ is less than $1$ to obtain the number of occurences of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n!\,$. Is that about right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly :)

Comment: (If this answers your question, please don't forget to accept it by clicking the tick $\ddot\smile$)

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy and just came back to this. I'm still trying to apply this result. Looking again at $$\binom{2m}{m}
= \frac{(2m)!}{(m!)^2} \, .$$ The condition is that $p^k$ divides $\binom{2m}{m}$. So $k$ is at most $\left\lfloor \frac{2m}{p} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{2m}{p^2} \right\rfloor + \ldots$ because it must divide the denominator. But that's not sufficient for $p^k \leq 2m$. So I need to consider the exponent of $p$ in the numerator, too. Eventually, I can substract that and should come up with something small enough to guarantee $p^k \leq 2m$, but I don't see how.

Comment: Another hint: consider $$\alpha_{2n, p}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $c_k$ be the integer such that $p^{c_k}\leq k\leq p^{c_k+1}$. For integer $n$, the number of elements in $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ divided by $p^j$ is $\lfloor \frac{n}{p^j} \rfloor$ then $c_{n!}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}\lfloor \frac{n}{p^i} \rfloor$ thus $c_{\binom{2m}{m}}=c_{\frac{(2m)!}{(m!)^2}}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{c_{2m}}\lfloor \frac{2m}{p^i} \rfloor-2(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{c_{2m}}\lfloor \frac{m}{p^i} \rfloor)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{c_{2m}}(\lfloor \frac{2m}{p^i} \rfloor-2\lfloor \frac{m}{p^i} \rfloor)$ but $\lfloor \frac{2m}{p^i} \rfloor-2\lfloor \frac{m}{p^i} \rfloor=0$ or $1$ by Euclidean division, thus $c_{\binom{2m}{m}}\leq c_{2m}$, $p^k\leq p^{c_{\binom{2m}{m}}}\leq p^{c_{2m}}\leq 2m$.